# Change Name/Description in windows context menu

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, context-menu

**How do I change the *MenuText/Description* in context menu?**

[image: Change context MenuText]

I went through bunch of context menu editors likes ContextEdit, ShellMenuNew, ShellNewHandler. None of these seems to give me an option to edit the ***MenuText***. How do I change it?

I also tried searching in registry using default *Registry Editor*, none of them helped me.

**Is it possible to add the name while creating context menu?**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html\ShellNew]
"FileName"="index.html"
"SOMEKEY"="New HTML5 Doc"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257543/adding-new-filetypes-to-windows-7s-new-context-menu

Comment: good catch loper, I see that the friendly type name from the regfile key was what was spawning the muicache setting I changed.

Answer (score 1):

Right idea, wrong key. You'll need to find the sister key and do two things.  First delete the "FriendlyTypeName" if it has one.  Then edit the default value.  I'll example you with .reg / regfile.

The .reg files template is in `HKCR\.reg`, but the "Registration Entries" text displayed in 'New' is from the `HKCR\regfile` default @ value.

Step 1) Delete / rename the 'FriendlyTypeName' if your key has one.

Step 2) Edit the default value to the new name.  Effect is immediate.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile]
@="Registration Entries"
"FriendlyTypeName"=-
```

Comment: Great Answer, Just to expand a bit. Go to you file type key, see what the data value of the (Default) is, this is the name of your sister key. It will be in the same directory as the file type key